# How to install the the lattest cocos2d-swift-3.2.1 in xcode 6.0.1?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, xcode6.0.1

I am trying to install the latest cocos2d as a template in xcode 6.0.1 but there is no install-template.sh file.I am not getting how to install it.I really appreciate if i can have some helpfull link or helpfull command in terminal.

thanks in Advance.

Comment: there currently is a problem with template installation, I believe this is explained on the cocos2d forum together with a workaround. Also try getting SpriteBuilder from AppStore it's supposed to install the cocos2d templates, this may be the easiest way.

Comment: Or use old versions, is not recommended, but  for  to learn this is a good alternative.